# Regex Match value in Typescript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract the value of certain pattern from the text.

Sample text:

```
Test: []
subtests: [a]
```

I want to extract the line `subtests: [a]` or precisely what's the data inside `[]` of subtests.
When I try to match the regex, it's giving wrong value. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

https://jsfiddle.net/k8e9hu0e/2/

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use `/g` global modifier and loop through all matches. If you need the contents inside `[...]`, you need a capture group. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8bf0ox5/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, can you please modify the code and show the solution to community? I am new to regex, it will be helpful for others like me

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/h8bf0ox5/. Or if you need to only show the match value, use `.exec(string)[0]` - https://jsfiddle.net/u1paL0y2/

Comment: All you had to do is read the docs: [*If the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array... The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/k8e9hu0e/4/)**.  So the only change was to remove the `captures` ie: changing `(.*)` to `.*`

Explaining your problem..

This regex `^subtests: (.*)` has captures in it. And when you find the matches for this regex, it gives you a set of all the regex matches and then all the capture's. So the first set is `subtests: []` and then the set of captures that is `[]`. Hence your output was `subtests: [],[]` (note the `,`).

Comment: @Reddy if this was the correct solution then you could mark it as answer.

Comment: Maybe a correct solution, but the explanation is not correct. *gives you a set of all the regex matches* - `RegExp#exec` does not yield an array of all matches, you need to use a loop to get all *matches*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, may be you can post an answer with explanation. Everyone will benefit. please

Comment: And @WiktorStribiżew that `Reddy` is the OP not the answerer :p

Answer (score 1):

Here is a live demo. Forked and modified from your source.
https://jsfiddle.net/soonsuweb/aj38617b/

```
var data = `blur blur subtests: [] blur\nblur`;
var regex = /subtests: \[.*\]/;
var test = regex.exec(data);
alert("Op: " + test);
```